# How to analyse Jar file?

Tags: java, jar, class-hierarchy

I want to analyze jar file, i.e. the code hierarchy (class diagram).  Which tools will be helpful for this?

Comment: Use an IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, etc.), import the JAR and look at it. Or do you want to create reports?

Answer (score 2):

If the JAR file contains compiled .class files, I would suggest JD-Gui. Type that on Google. That what I use everyday to have an overlook at methods signature and public functions etc..!